# How can deploy Wso2 in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, wso2, wso2-api-manager

when I want to change wso2'DB to Oracle I got this error.
what shall I do?
here are my tables and my settings
please help me.
Thank you so much

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: From a quick scan of [the source code](https://github.com/biliroy/carbon4-kernel/blob/master/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/JDBCUserStoreConstants.java), it looks like `isExistingDomain` will be executing query `SELECT UM_DOMAIN_ID FROM UM_DOMAIN WHERE UM_DOMAIN_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?` - so does that table exist, either in that schema or in one it has access to? (And have you [asked WSO2](https://wso2.com/subscription/#support) for help?)

Comment: table(UM_DOMAIN_ID)   does not exist

Comment: what's the APIM version?

Comment: Did you run the script to create the `shared_db` tables as mentioned in Point 1 of [this guide](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-oracle/#executing-db-scripts-to-create-tables-on-oracle-database)

Comment: version is 3.2.0

Comment: I execute both oracle.sql files

Comment: Do I create any Db as shared_db ?

Comment: You need to create the carbon db separately using `<API-M_HOME>/dbscripts/oracle.sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown when you dont configure the shared db properly. Run the oracle scripts under APIM_HOME/dbcripts/oracle.sql into a separate user schema and point it as follows.

```
[database.shared_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl1"
username = "sharedadmin"
password = "sharedadmin"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
```

then run the script under APIM-HOME/dbscripts/apimgt/oracle.sql and point it as follows.

```
[database.apim_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl2"
username = "apimadmin"
password = "apimadmin"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
```

It is not mandatory to configure local db to oracle if you do not have a special need. You can remove the [database.local] config to keep it in h2 itself.

Comment: I created 2 schemas and executed both of query to create tables , but the error hasn't gone

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the steps in [1] to setup Oracle as the database with APIM 3.2.0?

If you need to have the WSO2CARBON_DB also in Oracle, you need to create a separate database and execute the sql script in `<API-M_HOME>/dbscripts/oracle.sql` and then change the `[database.local]` configuration in deployment.toml according as mentioned in the Info section at the bottom of the above documentation

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-oracle/#executing-db-scripts-to-create-tables-on-oracle-database

Comment: yes I followed .

Comment: If you have multiple APIM instances, you need to have a WSO2CARBON_DB for each of those. Also, can you check whether the created database has the `UM_DOMAIN` table?